# AppleScript call function in IF statement

Tags: macos, applescript

I don't usually use function, but why can't I call a function inside an IF statement?

for example this obviously work just fine

```
notification()
on notification()
    display notification "just a quick demo"
end notification
```

but this doesn't :

```
set myOption to {"demo one", "demo two"}
set selectedoption to choose from list myOption with title "demo" with prompt "What's the story?" default items "Start Prism"

if selectedoption is equal to "demo one" then
    notification()
end if


on notification()
    display notification "just a quick demo"
end notification
```

Comment: Note that `choose from list` returns a _list_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your If statement isn't checking out.

Change "is equal to" to "contains", it should catch it.

```
if selectedoption contains "demo one" then
    notification()
end if
```